# PyTorch: VGG16 model not deterministic when ResNet18 model is

Tags: python, machine-learning, resnet, vgg-net

I currently try to learn two models (VGG16 ad ResNet18) on two Datasets (MNIST and CIFAR10). The goal here is to later test the effect different changes (like another loss function, or a manipulated dataset) have on the accuracy of the model. To make my results comparable I tried to make the learning process deterministic. To achieve this I set a fixed see for all the random generators with the following code.

```
def update_seed(seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
```

And for the ResNet18 model this works perfectly fine (The results are deterministic). But for the VGG16 model this does not work. And that is the point I don't understand, why is the above enough for ResNet18 to be deterministic, but not for VGG16?
So where is this extra randomness for VGG16 coming from and how can I disable it?
To get VGG16 deterministic I currently have to disable cuda and use the cpu only, but this makes the whole computing process very slow and is therefor not really an option.

The only difference between the two models is loading seen below and the learning rate when using CIFAR10.

```
def setup_vgg16(is_mnist_used):
    vgg16_model = models.vgg16()

    if is_mnist_used:
        vgg16_model.features[0] = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    vgg16_model.classifier[-1] = nn.Linear(4096, 10, bias=True)

    return vgg16_model


def setup_resnet(is_mnist_used):
    resnet_model = models.resnet18()

    if is_mnist_used:
        resnet_model.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
    resnet_model.fc = nn.Linear(512, 10, bias=True)

    return resnet_model
```

**What I have already tried** (but with no success):

Adding bias=False to the VGG16 model, as it is the obvious difference between the two models

Testing the model before the learning (maybe the model is initiated with random values), but without learning the model is deterministic

Adding more stuff to the `update_seed(seed)` function

- torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
- torch.backends.cudnn.enabled =    False (These two just decreases the
  performance)
- torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True) -> This results in a cuda
  error

Set num_worker=0 in the dataloader (this was suggested as a workaround for a similar problem in another thread)

This is the training function. Before this function the model is deterministic and after it is called for the first time, VGG16 is no longer deterministic.

```
def train_loop(dataloader, f_model, f_loss_fn, f_optimizer):
    # setting the model into the train mode
    f_model.train()

    for batch, (x, y) in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader)):
        # Moving the data to the same device as the model
        x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)

        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = f_model(x)
        loss = f_loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        f_optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        f_optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because [torchvision's VGG models](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/vgg.html) use `AdaptiveAvgPool2d`, and `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` cannot be made non-deterministic and [will throw a runtime error](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.use_deterministic_algorithms.html) when used together with `torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)`.